Stick with the same target behind an AWS load balancer
I have an application using sticky session, controlled by a load balancer. As the owner of a session I want to be able to share a link to bring another user/device to collaborate to the same session.
I was suggested to use something like redis to share information between all the targets. Then, even if the collaborator session is routed to a different target the application would still work properly. In my opinion this defeats the purpose of having a load balancer, as now we have another bottle neck that is the communication between the pods.
Ideally I would like the collaborator(s) to stick with the same target as the owner.
This is how I imagine this process

The owner creates a link with a session identifier.
The collaborator requests GET ${link}
The server checks uses the session identifier from the request (accessing e.g. redis, disk, or a database), then adds a Set-Cookie in the collaborator session that will cause subsequent requests of that client to be routed to the correct target.

This smells like a use case for application-based stickiness, but what should I do in the step 3.
Key questions

If I simply copy an automatically generated cookie in other requests, is it guaranteed to reach the same target (within the expiration time), even from different devices?
If I switch to application-based stickiness and give a UUID for each new session would it penalise the load balance?
If I clear the cookie e.g. with Set-Cookie: LOAD_BALANCER_COOKIE=; Max-Age=0 will it also clear it from the load balancer "memory", what is the way to tell the load balancer to forget a session?


"In my opinion this defeats the purpose of having a load balancer, as now we have another bottle neck that is the communication between the pods." Except Redis is extremely fast and isn't going to be a bottleneck in this type of scenario. Using Redis for this would also solve other issues, like what happens to your users when you deploy a new version of your application, or when a scale-down event in your target group occurs.

Pushing state to another tier like redis and keeping your service stateless will ensure proper load balancing and will improve availability.
Anyway to answer your key questions:
1/ and 2/: The load-balancer will use the content of the cookie to route to the proper target, so yes if you share its value with another device the requests will land on the same service instance.
3/: The load-balancer is stateless, it does not manage state in memory, it persists state in the cookie. It might be possible to clear the cookie in the output of your service, the trick is that the load-balancer manages the creation of a new cookie when there's none.

By your answer to 3, I understand that even if I use an application session ID cookie  the load balancer will still have to add a cookie for stickiness and will still rely on that specific cookie (not my session cookie) to route the connections? In this case what is the role of the application cookie in the load balancing?

OK, I spent the day doing this, but it seems that (1) the AWSALB is removed from the request cookies sent to the pod. (2) even if I add Set-Cookie: AWSALB=* the load balancer will add their own value. Does it mean that I have no option other than moving to application-based stickiness?
